# XAMPP PHP on Windows: Permission Denied Error despite having permissions

Tags: php, json, filesystems, fopen

I am trying to write a JSON into a `file.json`:

```
$json = json_encode($json);
//chmod('file.json', 777);
$file = fopen('file.json','w');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);
```

I am using XAMPP on Windows 10, I've checked and assigned **"Total control"** to **"All"** users in all directories.

And I am still getting the same errors:

> **Warning**:  fopen(file.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in **D:\xampp\htdocs\app\settings.php** on line **49**
>   
>   **Warning**:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **D:\xampp\htdocs\app\settings.php** on line **50**
>   
>   **Warning**:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **D:\xampp\htdocs\app\settings.php** on line **51**

Where have I something wrong? How to solve this?